# Which is better in C or even C++?

Tags: c, struct, enums, typedef, unions

I mean, what is better, or is there actually a difference?

```
typedef struct MyStruct {...} SomeName; // this one?
typedef struct {...} SomeName           // or this one
```

And also does it depend if I use typedef for structs, unions or enums?

Should I even bother about this?

Comment: never typedef a struct in C++. It's useless

Comment: Do you need a structure tag?  If so, use the first.  Otherwise you can use the second.

Comment: You didn't even include my personal preference: `struct MyStruct {...};` (no typedef).

Comment: @TomKarzes what is a structure tag?

Comment: Whatever is idiomatic ("best") in C will almost invariably won't be in C++ and vice-versa. So I'd encourage you to consider every language in isolation.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica ok, mainly this question is about C, can you give an answer pls?

Comment: That's often true, @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, but in this case, I assert that using a tag and avoiding `typedef` is a pretty good choice for both C and C++. Though how such a type is idiomatically *referenced* will differ between the two languages.

Comment: So I can use both, without even thinking about their difference? And how acceptable it could be if I never use typdef in C?

Comment: @SargisChshmarityan Structure tags are what your question is about.  If you have `struct foo`, then `foo` is a structure tag for that structure.  So your question is "Is it better to omit structure tags when they aren't needed?"

Comment: The difference is that one provides a structure *tag* (`MyStruct`) and the other doesn't.  In most cases you want either a tag or a typedef.  In some cases you *need* the tag, but in no case do you need the typedef.  In C, without the typedef, you must refer to the type as `struct MyStruct` (the `struct` keyword is mandatory in that case).

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have never heard of such a case that would require a structure tag. Can you link me to such a case? My Google-Fu isn’t very strong right now.

Comment: @SafelyFast Not absolutely required, but a usually desired case would be a structure for a node in a linked list or a tree. It needs to contain a member(s) of type pointer to that same type. A typedef name won't be available for that use unless it is forward declared before the structure declaration.

Comment: @SafelyFast, you need a tag to define a structure type that contains a self pointer.  If you've never run into that then you must never have implemented a linked list or a tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name space for `struct`, `union` and `enum` tags is separate from the global name space share by global variables functions and typedefs.

Both proposed structure definitions are possible in both `C` and `C++`:

```
typedef struct MyStruct {...} SomeName; // this one?
typedef struct {...} SomeName           // or this one
```

But they are not interchangeable.

In C++, the `typedef` is not necessary for the `struct` tag to ba available as a type name. The definition `struct SomeName { ... };` has an almost identical effect as the definition `typedef struct SomeName { ... } SomeName;` which would be necessary in C for this definition:

```
SomeName s;
```

I would recommend using the same identifier for the `struct` tag and the `typedef` is you bother to define global names.  Yet it using `struct SomeName` explicitly in code may help the next reader of you code understand that `SomeName` is not a scalar type:

```
typedef struct SomeName {...} SomeName;
```

or

```
struct SomeName {...};

// optional, before or after the struct definition
typedef struct SomeName SomeName;
```

Finally, it is usually recommended to avoid hiding pointers behind typedefs, as it may make the code more confusing.

Comment: I know that both are possible, I just wanted to know if there is difference between them, and if there is, what and when should I use